# ERROR: cannot determine package name from URL or path

Tags: package, julia

I have a repo whose name is not a standard Julia module name, say `git@github.com:ylxdzsw/oh-my-julia.jl.git`.

I used to develop and use it via `Pkg.clone("git@github.com:ylxdzsw/oh-my-julia.jl.git", "OhMyJulia")` and it works well. However, it is deprecated and the equivalent way to clone a package in Julia 0.7 is using `] dev git@github.com:ylxdzsw/oh-my-julia.jl.git`, but where should I specify the package name?

```
(v0.7) pkg> dev git@github.com:ylxdzsw/oh-my-julia.jl.git OhMyJulia
  Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
  Updating git-repo `git@github.com:ylxdzsw/oh-my-julia.jl.git`
ERROR: cannot determine package name from URL or path: git@github.com:ylxdzsw/oh-my-julia.jl.git

julia> using Pkg

julia> Pkg.develop(PackageSpec(url="git@github.com:ylxdzsw/oh-my-julia.jl.git", name="OhMyJulia"))
  Updating git-repo `git@github.com:ylxdzsw/oh-my-julia.jl.git`
ERROR: cannot determine package name from URL or path: git@github.com:ylxdzsw/oh-my-julia.jl.git
Stacktrace:
 [1] pkgerror(::String) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/Types.jl:120
 [2] parse_package!(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Pkg.Types.PackageSpec, ::String) at ./logging.jl:313
 [3] (::getfield(Pkg.Types, Symbol("##25#28")){Pkg.Types.Context,Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1},String})(::LibGit2.CachedCredentials) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/Types.jl:567
 [4] shred!(::getfield(Pkg.Types, Symbol("##25#28")){Pkg.Types.Context,Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1},String}, ::LibGit2.CachedCredentials) at ./secretbuffer.jl:184
 [5] handle_repos_develop! at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/Types.jl:498 [inlined]
 [6] #add_or_develop#13(::Symbol, ::Bool, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:52
 [7] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [8] #add_or_develop#12 at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:29 [inlined]
 [9] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [10] #add_or_develop#10(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Symbol,Any,Tuple{Symbol,Symbol},NamedTuple{(:mode, :shared),Tuple{Symbol,Bool}}}, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.PackageSpec) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:27
 [11] #add_or_develop at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [12] #develop#19 at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:70 [inlined]
 [13] develop(::Pkg.Types.PackageSpec) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v0.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:70
 [14] top-level scope at none:0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `name` is discarded if you already provide a `url`. Julia tries to parse your project's URL to extract the name. However, you used dash (`-`) in what should be the Package name. This eventually gives an error because types in julia cannot have dash in between characters since it is an operator.

You can specify the name of the package by creating a project file (i.e. `Project.toml`) for your package's root directory with correct `name` entry.

Another simple solution is to change the repository's name to `OhMyJulia` without the dashes so the name can be determined from the URL provided. But you should add `Project.toml` file it is the correct way to specify package properties (otherwise you cannot use your project within another project that contains a project file)

See: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Pkg/

Comment: Thanks. That means if I want to keep my URL, I had to manually edit those `Project.toml`s and `Manifest.toml`s in my repo and `~/.julia/environment`, right?

Comment: I tried adding only `Project.toml` file and the error was gone. I do not know about the julia environment. `Manifest.toml` file is used for dependencies not for the name of your package. You might need it though.

Comment: I suggest you that you use a `Project.toml` file. Projects without this file can be loaded for legacy reasons and with some restrictions. I edited my answer to reflect that.